# Multiple Custom Post Type in Taxonomy Archive Causing White Screen

Tags: wordpress

So basically I'm trying to add multiple custom post type in my taxonomy archive. Here's my code:

```
        <?php
    $args_trip = array ( 
        'post_type' => 'trip' ,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array (
            array ( 
                'taxonomy' => 'destination',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term
            )
        )
    );

    $trips = new WP_Query( $args_trip );        
    ?>

    <?php 
    if ( $trips->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div class="archive-grid">
        <?php
            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( $trips->have_posts() ) : $trips->the_post();
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'trip' );

            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();            

    ?>
        </div>
        <hr>

<?php 
$args_wisata = array ( 
    'post_type' => 'wisata' ,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array (
        array ( 
            'taxonomy' => 'destination',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $term
        )
    )
);

$wisatas = new WP_Query( $args_wisata );

if ( $wisatas->have_posts() ) : 
?>

<div class="archive-grid">

<?php
    /* Start the Loop */
    while ( $wisatas->have_posts() ) : $wisatas->the_post(); get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'wisata' );


    endwhile;

?>

</div>
```

The code above meant to output TWO different custom post type TRIP & WISATA within taxonomy archive.

BUT it always causing white screen, but when it only looping ONE custom post type, it works fine. Here's the code for only one custom post type:

```
        <?php
    $args_trip = array ( 
        'post_type' => 'trip' ,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array (
            array ( 
                'taxonomy' => 'destination',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term
            )
        )
    );

    $trips = new WP_Query( $args_trip );        
    ?>

    <?php 
    if ( $trips->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div class="archive-grid">
        <?php
            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( $trips->have_posts() ) : $trips->the_post();
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'trip' );

            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();            

    ?>
        </div>
        <hr>
```

I don't know what might be causing this? Really frustrate me... Please someone help me! Lol.

Comment: Edit your **wp_config.php** file and change  **define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );** to  **define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );**   and then refresh your page. You should be able pinpoint the error ....

Comment: my `wp-config.php` already has `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` but there is no error shown, only blank white page. @Jamie_D

Comment: You should be able to track down the error in your apache/web server logs. Also try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script to see if that reports anything. It's also possible that the error is not related to your script, in which case you should check this page: [link] https://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to close the if - add `<?php endif; ?>` after those two `</div>` (the closing tag for the archive-grid DIV)

And voilà it's working! Sorry i've been blind the whole time.